Chainlink Functions: RWA Tokenization (Minting 0 tokens)
When trying to call the mintStockTokens function from the fulfillRequest function the callback fails in the functions dashboard. I believe this is due to chainlink gas limits.
If i call the mintStockTokens function from the depositAndMint function no tokens are minted because the request hasn't been fulfilled yet.
Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this problem.
This is my contract :
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.25;

import {FunctionsClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/FunctionsClient.sol";
import {ConfirmedOwner} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import {FunctionsRequest} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/libraries/FunctionsRequest.sol";
import {MintableToken} from "./MintableToken.sol";
import {OracleLib, AggregatorV3Interface} from "./OracleLib.sol";

contract Synthetic is FunctionsClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using FunctionsRequest for FunctionsRequest.Request;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal dataFeed;

    bytes32 public s_lastRequestId;
    bytes public s_lastResponse;
    bytes public s_lastError;
    uint64 subscriptionId;
    uint256 public stockPrice;
    uint256 maxMintableTokenValueInUsd;
    string public newStockName;
    string public newStockSymbol;

    //test vars
    uint256 public depositValue;
    uint256 public maxMintableTokenValueInUsdTest;
    uint256 public NoOFTokensToMint;
    int256 public ethPriceInUsd;
    // Custom error type
    error UnexpectedRequestID(bytes32 requestId);

    // Event to log responses
    event Response(
        bytes32 indexed requestId,
        string character,
        bytes response,
        bytes err
    );

    event TokensMinted(address indexed user, uint256 amount, address token);
    event RequestFulfilled(address user, string stockName, string stockSymbol, uint256 tokensToMint);

    // address router = 0xC22a79eBA640940ABB6dF0f7982cc119578E11De; //amoy network
    address router = 0xb83E47C2bC239B3bf370bc41e1459A34b41238D0; //sepolia network

    // JavaScript source code
    string source =
        "const ticker = args[0];"
        "const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({"
        "url: `https://chainlink-wine.vercel.app/api/alpha/${ticker}`"
        "});"
        "if (apiResponse.error) {"
        "throw Error('Request failed');"
        "}"
        "const { data } = apiResponse;"
        "const dataMultiplied = data * 100;"
        "return Functions.encodeUint256(dataMultiplied);";

    //Callback gas limit
    uint32 gasLimit = 300000;

    bytes32 donID =
        // 0x66756e2d706f6c79676f6e2d616d6f792d310000000000000000000000000000;// amoy network
        0x66756e2d657468657265756d2d7365706f6c69612d3100000000000000000000;// sepolia network

    mapping(address => uint256) public depositedAmount;
    mapping(address => MintableToken) public syntheticTokens;
    mapping(address => address[]) public walletToContractAddresses;


    constructor(uint64 _subId)
        FunctionsClient(router)
        ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender)
    {
        subscriptionId = _subId;
        dataFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(
            // 0xF0d50568e3A7e8259E16663972b11910F89BD8e7// eth/usd amoy network
            // 0x001382149eBa3441043c1c66972b4772963f5D43// matic/usd amoy network
            0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306 // sepolia network
        );
    }

    function getChainlinkDataFeedLatestAnswer() public view returns (int256) {
        // prettier-ignore
        (
            /* uint80 roundID */,
            int answer,
            /*uint startedAt*/,
            /*uint timeStamp*/,
            /*uint80 answeredInRound*/
        ) = dataFeed.latestRoundData();
        return answer;
    }

    function sendRequest(string[] calldata args)
        internal
        returns (
            // onlyOwner
            bytes32 requestId
        )
    {
        FunctionsRequest.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequestForInlineJavaScript(source);
        if (args.length > 0) req.setArgs(args);
        s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(
            req.encodeCBOR(),
            subscriptionId,
            gasLimit,
            donID
        );

        return s_lastRequestId;
    }

    function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    ) internal override {
        if (s_lastRequestId != requestId) {
            revert UnexpectedRequestID(requestId);
        }

        s_lastResponse = response;
        uint256 newPrice = convertBytesToUint(response);
        stockPrice = newPrice * 1e16;
        s_lastError = err;
        stockTokensToMint(ethPriceInUsd, stockPrice);
        // emit RequestFulfilled(msg.sender, newStockName, newStockSymbol, NoOFTokensToMint);
        // **************************************************************************
        // if you mint here there is a gas error from chainlink but cannot increase gas from chainlink 3000000 is max
        //or could be due to the msg.sender is not being sent to the mintStockToken function
        // **************************************************************************
        // mintStockTokens(newStockName, newStockSymbol, NoOFTokensToMint);
        
    }


    function depositAndMint(
        string memory _name, // name of the stock
        string memory _symbol, // symbol of the stock
        string[] calldata _stock
    ) external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Insufficient deposit amount");
        depositedAmount[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        newStockName = _name;
        newStockSymbol = _symbol;
        ethPriceInUsd = getChainlinkDataFeedLatestAnswer() * 1e10;
        uint256 depositValueInUsd = (uint256(ethPriceInUsd) * msg.value) / 1e18;
        depositValue = depositValueInUsd;
        sendRequest(_stock);

        // **************************************************************************
        // if you mint here there are 0 tokens issued as the sendRequest has not been fulfilled 
        // **************************************************************************
        // mintStockTokens(newStockName, newStockSymbol, NoOFTokensToMint);
        
    }

    function mintStockTokens(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        uint256 tokensToMint
    ) internal {
        MintableToken newToken = new MintableToken(
            _name,
            _symbol,
            tokensToMint
        );
        syntheticTokens[msg.sender] = newToken;
        newToken.mint(msg.sender, tokensToMint);

        //store minted tokens to address mapping
        walletToContractAddresses[msg.sender].push(address(newToken));
        //emit an event for total minted tokens to address
        emit TokensMinted(msg.sender, tokensToMint, address(newToken));
    }
//  ***************************************************************
// Still to solve the redeemAndBurn function 
//  ***************************************************************
    // function redeemAndBurn(uint256 amountToBurn) external {
    //     require(
    //         syntheticTokens[msg.sender].balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amountToBurn,
    //         "Insufficient token balance"
    //     );
    //     syntheticTokens[msg.sender].burn(msg.sender, amountToBurn);
    //     uint256 redeemAmount = (amountToBurn * DEPOSIT_AMOUNT) /
    //         syntheticTokens[msg.sender].totalSupply();
    //     depositedAmount[msg.sender] -= redeemAmount;
    //     payable(msg.sender).transfer(redeemAmount);
    // }


    function convertBytesToUint(bytes memory response)
        public
        pure
        returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 newprice = abi.decode(response, (uint256));
        // stockPrice = newprice;
        return newprice;
    }

    function bytesToUint(bytes32 _bytes) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return uint256(_bytes);
    }

    function stockTokensToMint(int256 _ethPrice, uint256 _stockPrice) internal {
       NoOFTokensToMint = (uint256(_ethPrice) / _stockPrice) / 2;
       mintStockTokens(newStockName, newStockSymbol, NoOFTokensToMint);
    }
    // for testing to remove funds
    function withdraw() public {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}

The entire repo can be found on : https://github.com/leetebbs/chainlink/blob/main/hardhat/contracts/SyntheticV2.sol

Hi Eik, to debug the codes, you have to know if the request is sent successfully to Chainlink Functions. Head to the Functions app(https://functions.chain.link/) to check the status of the request, if you cannot see the request, then the request is not sent successfully. If the request is there, check the status to see why the fulfillment function is not called. Based on my experience, maybe you need to increase the gas limit for functions.
